# Node - Trigger key/key combination on server

Tags: node.js, autohotkey

I was wondering if it's possible to make node emit keyboard events to the host's os.

(something like autoHotKey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) project aims to do what you are describing. Though I have not used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you really like AutoHotkey, then you could simply trigger an AutoHotkey script from NodeJS. Somehting like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
exec('"%programfiles%/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey.exe" "C:/test.ahk"')
```

Since your question is lacking any kind of details, I'm just assuming that you are running Windows and have AutoHotkey installed.